# Create Non Conflicting Numbers to Store in Database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to create some unique increment numbers to store in the database.

For instance

```
s-001
s-002
s-003
s-004
```

Every time a new record is inserted into the database it should increment by 1 and no duplicates can be allowed.

I already have a PK on the table so this is acting as more as a short hand for the primary key, also since this is not just straight up numbers it would not work anyways.

I am doing this in C#, with Entity Framework.

I am looking for simple ways to achieve this and nothing too complex as I don't have time to make a super robust solution and the chances of duplicates are very low (only 1 method so far will be making this and it runs synchronously) but if it did happen and duplicates did happen it would be devastating.

I heard people of making a table that stores the last value in it and then you look at that table to get the last value and then you do some checks before inserting and if there are duplicates you let it fail?

My primary key is a GUID, so I can't append what I want to it.

Comment: Can you not just concatenate `s-` with the PK, or with a new `IDENTITY` column?

Comment: The PK, is already built and has to be a GUID. Not sure what you mean by another Identity column?

Comment: Sorry I thought the PK was an `IDENTITY` (auto-increment). Create an `IDENTITY` column, then create a computed column off that `'s-' + myIDcolumn`

Comment: I am not sure my boss will like it as it will be seen as wasteful having another column that is not really being used.

Comment: A computed column doesn't take up any space unless it is `PERSISTED` or in an index

Comment: If you don't want to "waste" on a column - try using a `SEQUENCE` in SQL Server - but then you need to also do a lot more manually, like fetch the next value from the sequence, either in your EF code, or in a trigger

Comment: This column I am making up will need to be indexed as it will be used to access the records. Also it is not really like physical space it is just adding another column to tables that already have enough columns

Comment: @marc_s - sequence looks like a possible option, I am assuming you can have many sequences if you want and not just confined to making one. Also I am guessing even if 10 request at the same time request a sequence they will be all guaranteed to be unquie?

Comment: You can have multiple sequences, and yes, the work very similarly to an `identity` column in that SQL Server guarantees to hand out only unique values

Comment: @marc_s I was reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 

and it sounds like duplicates still can happen. Maybe I am wrong in how this will all work but I would generate the sequence number, append my letter to it and then save it in a column on my table. So even if the sequence autofixes it self or warns about duplicates I am not sure if a duplicate would hit my table. Can you give a full example of how you envision it would work?

Comment: Duplicates *could* happen if you recycle a sequence, or let it "wrap around" when it reaches its maximum; but if you don't do either of these two things, then there are no duplicates.

Comment: @marc_s - ok that is great to hear. I will try it out and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed column : an IDENTITY Column + 'S'

Comment: though, I do like this idea. I don't think my boss will as it means a useless column in the database.